# How to use HashRouter in React?

Tags: reactjs, github

I'm developing a website that has two addresses, `/` and `/admin`. In `/` I have a menu that forwards to each of the site's sessions. For routing to work I initially used BrowserRouter and everything worked. However, when I uploaded to Github the site stopped working, with a white screen.

I noticed that on Github we should use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter, so I made the change, but the site didn't work locally, on my localhost. It only worked when I uploaded it to github. And another problem is that now the links (`<Link to="#section">`) to the site sections don't work either.

Link to GitHub: priscilasilvaalves.github.io/portfolio2/build

How do I make the site work on localhost and click on links that forward to different sessions also work? Why does HashRouter not work locally on my machine?

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "../App";
import Admin from "./admin";

function RouteSwitch(){
    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <Routes>    
                <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
                <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
            </Routes>
        </HashRouter>
    );
}

export default RouteSwitch;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from "./components/header";
import Main from "./components/main";
import Footer from "./components/footer";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import './App.css';
import Contato from "./components/contato";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Contato />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Admin.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/admin/admin.css";
import "../styles/admin/admin-titulo.css";
import "../styles/admin/admin-mensagem.css";
import "../styles/admin/admin-mensagem-item.css";

function Admin(){
    const [dados, setDados] = useState("");
    
    async function pegarDados(){
        let url = "http://localhost/portfolio/javascript/src/api/recuperar-mensagem.php";
        try{
            const response = await fetch (url, {mode: 'cors'});
            const getData = await response.json();
            let arr = [];
            let j =0;
            for(let i=getData.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                arr[i]=getData[j];
                j++;
            }
            setDados(arr);
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        pegarDados();
    }, []);

    return (
        <section className="admin">
            <h1 className="admin__titulo">Caixa de Entrada</h1>
            {
                dados !== "" ?
                dados.map((elemento) => (
                    <div className="admin__mensagem" key={elemento.id}>
                        <p className="admin__mensagem-item">Nome: {elemento.nome}</p>
                        <p className="admin__mensagem-item">E-mail: {elemento.email}</p>
                        <p className="admin__mensagem-item">Assunto: {elemento.assunto}</p>
                        <p className="admin__mensagem-item">Mensagem: {elemento.mensagem}</p>
                    </div>
                ))
                : null
            }
        </section>
    );
}

export default Admin;
```

Nav.js:

```
import "../styles/nav/nav.css";
import "../styles/nav/nav-ul.css";
import "../styles/nav/nav-li.css";
import "../styles/nav/nav-a.css";
import "../styles/nav/nav-imagem.css";
import "../styles/nav/nav-button.css";
import Tracos from "../images/tracos.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Nav(){
    function showMenu(){
        let ul = document.querySelector(".nav__ul");
        if(ul.style.display===""){
            ul.style.display="flex";
        }else if(ul.style.display==="flex"){
            ul.style.display="";
        }
    }
    return (
        <nav className="nav">
            <button className="nav__button" onClick={ () => showMenu() }>
                <img className="nav__imagem" src={ Tracos } alt="" />
            </button>
            <ul className="nav__ul">
                <li className="nav__li"><Link className="nav__a" to="#cabecalho">Início</Link></li>
                <li className="nav__li"><Link className="nav__a" to="#quem-e">Quem é Priscila?</Link></li>
                <li className="nav__li"><Link className="nav__a" to="#formacao">Formação</Link></li>
                <li className="nav__li"><Link className="nav__a" to="#projetos">Projetos</Link></li>
                <li className="nav__li"><Link className="nav__a" to="#contato">Contato</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Nav;
```

Comment: You should use `<Link>` not `<a>`. Also the problem might be different. Open network tab and see if js loads

Comment: I did that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I would guess that J's doesn't load at all

Comment: could you add **App** and **Admin** componenents  as well

Comment: Ok I upload the question

Comment: are you importing **RouteSwitch** componenent to **index.js** file if it's yes than check **index.js** file it might be using **browserRouter**

Comment: when you use **<Link>** you should use **to** attribute . like this ` <Link to={path} >name of path</Link>`

Comment: I am importing RouteSwitch into index.js file correctly. How would I be using BrowserRoute in the index.js file? In the RouteSwitch.js file, the HashRouter is being used.